# Delete a row from VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to establish a PIM listener that will update a MainScreen where all the contacts of the phone are listed.

What I am doing is the following:

- I am loading for one time only a form called ContactsForm and I am storing it into the RuntimeStore
- I created a PIMListListener to listen for all the changes that will occur in the address book.
- When a contact is added, I am adding it to the contactsForm successfully
- When a contact is removed, I am facing a big problem deleting it :S!!!

I am getting this exeption: "IllegalArgumentException"; this exception's text is : UiEngine accessed without holding the event lock. I know such errors and I know how to resolve them. So I used the following code:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() { public void run() {
  synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
     uiContacts.vm.delete(uiContacts.vm.getField(j));
  }
}});
```

This should resolve the problem. But I keep getting this error again and again. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listeners, like the PIMListListener, do not receive their callbacks in the same Application context as your UiApplication. So, in your code, `UiApplication.getUiApplication()` doesn't really work the way you'd expect it to.

The best thing to do would be to store a reference to your UiApplication in a place where the callback can reach it (during initialization of the UiApplication, perhaps), and then replace `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(...)` with `myUiApp.invokeLater(...)`, where `myUiApp` is the reference to your UiApplication which you stored earlier.